# Send message from server (tcplistener) to client (tcpclient)

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

My understanding for now about client-server connections in C#:

- TCPListener = Server
- TCPClient = Client

In alternative to this exists a "Socket" class which can be used as Client and as Server, but at the end do both variants the same thing?!

I understand the TCPClient. It has a getStream() method, which returns a NetWorkStream which has methods for read and write from/to the stream.

My problem is the TCPListener on the server-side. The TCPListener has not a getStream() method and also no read/write method. How i can read/write from the TCPListener from/to the stream?

Comment: `while(true)
            {
                var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                /*use tcpClient*/
            }`

Answer (score 2):

TCP supports bidirectional streaming. Once a connection is established, there's not much difference between the client and the server ends.

You would use [`TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to establish the connection and give the server side its `TcpClient` instance.

You mention sending messages in your question title. One important thing to bear in mind is that if you're working at this low level with `TCP`, there's no inherent "messaging" layer - calls of `Send` at one end are **not** matched 1-1 with calls of `Receive` at the other end. If you want messaging you have to build that yourself on top of these primitives, or switch to a higher level networking library (e.g. WCF) which automatically hides this level of detail.

---

Basically, the `TcpListener` class acts along the lines of "I intend to allow people to connect to me" - and calls to `Accept*` like methods are the way of saying "if anyone's currently asking to connect with me, let's create that connection now and start talking"

Answer (score 0):

TcpListener lets you accept incoming connections using eg. the `AcceptTcpClient` method. This returns a `TcpClient` instance you can use for bi-directional communication with the client.

TCP is a protocol built around connections, so you can't really send or receive data without estabilishing a connection first - that applies to both the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TcpClient's stream to both receive and send data from/to the client
the TcpListener only listens for requests, it cannot interact with them.